# UIWebView is zooming when I resize it. Can I tell it to stop doing that?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, resize, zooming

I'm using a UIWebView to display formatted text. It works fine until I start resizing it. When I do it starts zooming and the font size gets too big. Is there anyway to tell it not to zoom or reset the zoom?

Answer (score 0):

try setting the minimumZoomScale and maximumZoomScale of the uiwebview to 1.